# Is there a way to make the 'click here to begin' button at the bottom of the page but in the center within the script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, format

I created the button to be at the top of the page in the middle, but I need the button to be at the bottom of the page in the middle.

I have tried adding tags from HTML inside the script tag but it hasn't worked.

```
var buttonOne = `<h1><center><button class="btn">Click Here to Start</button></center></h1>`;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
```

Comment: <center> tag Is not supported in html5. Use proper CSS to style the element. Also the style of the element depends on other elements so please share a extended code sample.

Comment: var instructions = `<h1><center>You will see three symbols appear</center></h1>`;
var buttonOne = `<h1><center><button class="btn">Click Here to Start</button></center></h1>`;
   document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 32) { //32 is for spacebar look online for javascript keycode sheet if you want the page to move forward by pressing another key

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can use `$(buttonOne).append('body');` this add your button at the end of the code that generally display it at bottom , if this doesn't work may be use this instead

```
var buttonOne = `<h1 style="width:100%,position:absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0" ><center><button class="btn">Click Here to Start</button></center></h1>`;
```

Comment: it is appendTo and no it will not show at the bottom of the page without CSS as in the second example

Comment: it doesn't work, also I am trying to make the code without jQuery

Comment: does it change something by adding the the css to the `<h1>` tag ?